# Strange points of Casper algorithm

Tags: go-ethereum, network, casper

Currently, Ethereum developers are developing Casper Algorithm for Ethereum 2.0.
According to their proposal, some validator are chosen randomly but validators has permanently authority to verify transactions as long as they do not put down their validator's authority.

There are some other strange points and I would like to ask about them.

1. How many period they has the qualification that can verify some transactions and earn reward?
2. Assume that validators are chosen totally 1000 people, how they divide the reward for verification transaction which is in checkpoint block? for example, assume block reward is 3ETH so, Can each person earn the reward 3ETH/1000?
3. The time that validator do work is checkpoint time, generated in every 100 blocks. **I THINK THIS IS CONTRADICTION** because current Casper algorithm is based on PoW, which takes Nakamoto consensus. **Each miner in the world can't synchronize their chain(ledger database) due to Nakamoto Consensus** but how validators can verify in checkpoint? at that time, it absolutely cannot convinced that each miner has checkpoint. for example, some miner's block height is 189, some miner's block height is 195 due to async network. It can't convinced that all miners have 200 of block height. How think about it?

Sorry for my English.